# How to capture the screenshot of a specific element rather than entire page using Selenium Webdriver?I tried the already available answers

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to capture the screenshot of a specific element rather than entire page using Selenium Webdriver?Im using selenium 4.0.How to capture the screenshot of a specific element rather than entire page using Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: which language are you using ? java , python ?

Comment: Im using java should I use Ashot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check webelement class to know available methods:

in java:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

```
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66021499/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-a-specific-element-rather-than-entire-page-usin?noredirect=1#comment116730378_66021499");
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#submit-button"));
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  

   File a = new File("a.png");
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",element);
   File b = element.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
   FileUtils.copyFile(b, a);
```

in python :

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

```
element.screenshot(filename)
```

Comment: @ PDHide Can u share a full code for a sample website but taking a screenshot of a specific webelement .I think I have to scroll and take screenshot

Comment: It works .But where the screenshot is saved

Comment: @shivacurrent directory as a.png , you can also give a full path like c:/a.png to create file there

Comment: I found But I cant  take the complete screenshot Im able to take only half.I have to scroll down to take full screenshot

Comment: @shiva updated the code with scrolltolement could you try now

Comment: I want to click a button and select the dropdown .How can I do that